# How to link DLL file in classpath

Tags: java, apache, java-native-interface

I kept my DLL file in Apache's lib folder and try to run my server. It shows

> unsatisfied link error no DLL found in java.library.classpath.

How to make Tomcat Catalina to point to my DLL file in lib folder.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; acronym capitalization; layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to pass `-Djava.library.path=/directory/with/your/dll/file` inside Catalina startup script.

Alternatively, you can use `_JAVA_OPTIONS` variable. But make sure to pass all the options here as `_JAVA_OPTIONS` overrides anything else.